# render n number of components where n can change in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple question. If I have 1 component that gets rendered whenever a variable called count=1. How would I make this dynamic so that the number of components that get rendered will always equal count? I could do the if, else if but that would be tediuous. I was thinking something more like a for loop maybe? Here is some code I would like to render n times. It is simply a single component as shown below.

```
    return(
        <div>
            <SensorComponent user={props.user} 
                            moisture={value} 
                            historicalData={recentHistoricalData}
                            allHistoricalData={allHistoricalData}  
                            userInformation={userInformation}
                            setUserInformation={setUserInformation}
                            componentDetails={props.componentDetails}
                            setComponentDetails={props.setComponentDetails}
                            />
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Would the props all be the same? or would it be an array of different props?

Comment: The props will all be different

Answer (score 1):

You can just make an array from the count and iterate over it.

Here is an example which I made for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-curran-3oodk?file=/src/App.js

NOTE: this will create a new instance of an array on each re render, if you don't want that, you can always memoize your created array.

```js
const arr = useMemo(() => new Array(count).fill(), [count]);
```

and then

```
{arr.map((_, index) => <Component key={index} />)}
```

And if you want different props for all these components, then you would want to create an array with the different props/values and iterate over that.

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having the data needed for the component in an array, then iterate that array to create the components needed. A good example of this is a list of items, you would create the `<ul>../</ul>` bit and inside iterate through the array to generate the `

...

items. This is no different from what you want. So

you'd define an array of objects for the data e.g.

```
componentData = [{
  name: 'Name 1',
}, {
  name: 'name 2'
}]
```

Then in your render function, have some code like:

```
<ul>
  {
    componentData.map(data => <li>data.name</li>);
  }
</ul>
```

This will iterate through the `componentData`, creating a new component, configured with each individual `data` object, one per component.